# Angular 5 MatTableDataSource returns error "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OrderDataSource'"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to work with MatTables in Angular 5 and getting following error:

> ERROR in src/app/components/order/order.component.ts(30,59): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OrderDataSource'.

Here is my code:

**order.component.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

import { Order } from '../../models/order.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-order',
    templateUrl: './order.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./order.component.css']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['id', 'status', 'is_active'];

    dataSourceNewOrders = new MatTableDataSource();
    dataSourceOpenOrders = new MatTableDataSource();
    dataSourceProblemOrders = new MatTableDataSource();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.loadOrders();
    }

    loadOrders(){
        new OrderDataSource('problem').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.dataSourceProblemOrders.data = data;
        });

        new OrderDataSource('new').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.dataSourceNewOrders.data = data;
        });

        new OrderDataSource('in-progress').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.dataSourceOpenOrders.data = data;
        });
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class OrderDataSource{
    constructor(private orderType: string){    
    }

    connect(): Observable<Order[]> {
        let records: Order[] = [{
            id: 1,
            status: "new",
            is_active: true
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            status: "new",
            is_active: false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            status: "in-progress",
            is_active: true            
          }];

        return Observable.of(records).delay(500);

//        return this.orderService.readRecords({
//            'status': this.orderType
//        });
    }

    disconnect() {}
}
```

**order.model.ts**

```
export interface Order {
    id: number;
    client_id?: number;
    dealer_id?: number;

    status: string;
    is_active: boolean;
    date_created?: string;
    date_updated?: string;
}
```

Comment: you need to subscribe to the method returning observable not the class `new OrderDataSource('problem').connect().subscribe(...`

Comment: Yes correct, I missed out this. Also, when I tried to extend OrderDataSource by DataSource<any>, connect() should be automatically called, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `subscribe` to the method returning `observable` not the class

```
   loadOrders(){
            new OrderDataSource('problem').connect().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.dataSourceProblemOrders.data = data;
            });

            new OrderDataSource('new').connect().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.dataSourceNewOrders.data = data;
            });

            new OrderDataSource('in-progress').connect().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.dataSourceOpenOrders.data = data;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes correct, I missed out this. Also, when I tried to extend OrderDataSource by DataSource<any>, connect() should be automatically called, right?